# Using BeautifulSoup to find first string which comes after certain string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I find the first string which comes after a certain string using BeautfulSoup?

I have this text within an HTML file:

```
<tr>
<th scope="row">Continent:</th>
<td>North America</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

I'd like to fetch out of it "North America" by getting the first string which comes after 'Continent:' string.

How can I do that?

BTW, I found another way to get it, but I'm looking for a more simple way:

```
continent_tag = soup.find('th', string='Continent:')
print continent_tag.parent.contents[3].contents[0]
```

Thanks,

Moty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are siblings, another option would be to use the [`.find_next_sibling()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) in order to select the adjacent `td` sibling element:

```
print(soup.find('th', string='Continent:').find_next_sibling('td').text)
# North America
```